# Why aren't my @font-face declarations working on wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been trying to add some webfonts to my wordpress theme/ site, but I can't get them to work. I've added all the necessary files to my root folder, and I have tried using the following css to link them to my site.

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'AvenirNextLTPro-Demi';
src: url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.eot');
src: url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype',
url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.svg#svgAvenirNextLTPro-Demi') format('svg');
}
```

When I add the code above to the top of my stylesheet, it stops all the other css below it from working and I end up with a very ugly un-styled page, as well as the font itself not working.

I got the code from https://http://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/ which seems to be highly recommended by others.

Is anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Browser giving any errors back in the console? edit; after looking around a bit adding /wp-content to the url worked for someone else. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I've tried this already and it didn't make any difference. There's a message in the console that has been there for a while before I added this code, but I wasn't sure if it was an error as I'm not really experienced with using it. It says "GET" followed by my URL with /style.css at the end of it.

Comment: Could you post the full error message and your full header containing the links to your stylesheets?

Comment: I have my page template stylesheet followed by my main one which is: else { wp_enqueue_style( 'lucieaverillphotography_style', get_stylesheet_uri() ); } }

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the placement of your fonts. Are the fonts located on your-domain.com/fonts/YourFont.eot?

They are likely located under a theme, e.g. www.your-domain.com/wp-content/your-theme/fonts/YourFont.eot :-)

Comment: Hi Jannik, I wondered if it was to do with the location. I've saved them in my root folder via my FTP account under public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts (I added the fonts folder for organisation purposes) So am I supposed to take them out of my theme and add them to my domain? and if so, how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Where is your css located? :-) If it's located in e.g. /css (and your fonts are in /fonts), then just add two dots ".." in front of your font paths, and you should be golden! e.g. url('../fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.eot');

Comment: My css is located as a loose file in my theme folder, under the name style.css  – I tried adding the dots but unfortunately it made no difference

Comment: If it is directly under the theme folder, then write like this: url('fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi-webfont.eot'); (wtihout the dots, and without the first slash)

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid, it's disabling all the css below it and the font isn't showing up. Here's a screenshot of how my theme folder is laid out: http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Screen-Shot-2016-01-07-at-21.57.59.png

Comment: Ah, I've just taken a look on your website. The problem is that the style reference is wrong (404). You need to edit your master page, to reference the style.css to point to /wp-content/themes/lucieaverillphotography/style.css

Comment: Oh right, I used to have a stylesheet link at the top of my index before I started adding additional page templates and switched to referencing them in my functions folder. Is this what you mean ? – <link href="<?php bloginfo('/wp-content/themes/lucieaverillphotography/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Yup, exactly :-). But if you want it to be really awesome, try using the wordpress theme relative path: get_bloginfo('template_url') - should look somewhat like this: <link href="<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css');" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: I'm really not sure why, but none of the ones we've mentioned above are solving the problem. Do you know whether adding @font-face rules with mistakes in them usually causes entire stylesheets to fail until the offending code is fixed or removed? I'm also wondering about the stylesheet reference in the index. Would this not be taken care of by the php command (above in my comments to Stefan) in my functions.php? This is how I've been linking the stylesheet since I've needed to add separate ones for templates.

Comment: Hi Jack, unless there are missing end tags or the like, then no - should not break the entire stylesheet. Did you try to update the style reference? (i still see the same reference on the website as before, and it is still returning a file-not-found/404).

Comment: There is also something wrong with the markup. When I view-source, I see 2x body start tags. First body tag even starts before your HTML - this could also have an impact on the result you see :)

Comment: Hmm, one of those could be the Function Reference/body class that I added to make my page builder plugin work. I've taken a look at the view source page and checked the stylesheet. When I click on it, it takes me to a blank page with my logo and header links on it, whereas I'm guessing it should be showing the css? Anyway I've added the following code to the index:
 <link href="<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/lucieaverillphotography/style.css');" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this, I think I have all the necessary components, but somewhere along the line I've got mixed up as to where I should be putting all of them. I'm going to do a bit of research and check out how headers and index files should be arranged and see what I can come up with.